# How to update a document in Meteor with multiple input fields and a single update button

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've got a modal that pops up and lets the user update some fields in the collection. For example, it would have multiple input fields for a client's address (the modal has a single button to perform the update):

```
...
<input type="text" id="full-name-change-modal">
<input type="text" id="address-change-modal">
<input type="text" id="city-change-modal">
<input type="text" id="state-change-modal">
...
```

So if the user wants to change the full name of the client, the update would only include those fields where the appropriate input wasn't empty. In this case the update would read something like:

```
Collection.update({ _id: documentNameAddress._id}, {$set: {FullName: <name from input> }});
```

If the user wanted to change the address, city, state and zip, it'd need to read:

```
Demographic.update({ _id: documentNameAddress._id}, {$set: {Address: <address from input>, City: <city from input>, State: <state from input>, Zip: <zip from input> });
```

I'd rather not have a separate button for every field if possible. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't see the problem. What have you tried so far, i.e., what didn't work?

Comment: Apologies for my typo. "Collection" was meant to be the name of an arbitrary collection. "Demographic" is one of my collections, but that should have been "Collection" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll end up with one optional update for `Collection` and then you can build up update for `Demographic` based on the non-empty fields in the form:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click button':function(ev){

    var FullName = $("#full-name-change-modal").val();
    if ( FullName ) Collection.update({ _id: documentNameAddress._id}, {$set: {FullName: FullName }});

    var query = {};
    var Address = $('#address-change-modal').val();
    if ( Address ) query.Address = Address;
    var City = $('#city-change-modal').val();
    if ( City) query.City = City;
    var State = $('#state-change-modal').val();
    if ( State ) query.State = State;
    if ( Object.keys(query).length ) Demographic.update(query);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. While waking this morning, I came to the same solution, but yours was a little cleaner. Thank you!